# Python beautifulsoup scraping and collecting data

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

From [zillow](https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_rent/?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-122.48906135559082%2C%22east%22%3A-122.35413551330566%2C%22south%22%3A37.738955793388136%2C%22north%22%3A37.82727700595516%7D%2C%22mapZoom%22%3A13%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Afalse%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22price%22%3A%7B%22min%22%3A0%2C%22max%22%3A872627%7D%2C%22beds%22%3A%7B%22min%22%3A1%7D%2C%22fore%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22mp%22%3A%7B%22min%22%3A0%2C%22max%22%3A3000%7D%2C%22ah%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22auc%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22nc%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fr%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22fsbo%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22cmsn%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fsba%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%7D) I want to get every item in the unordered list and go to the specific class:

```
"StyledPropertyCardDataWrapper-c11n-8-84-3__sc-1omp4c3-0 bKpguY property-card-data"
```

Where I can get the price, address, and link creating 3 different lists including each of the wanted details.
I'm getting just empty blankets

tried this:

```
all_tags = soup.select(selector='body ul')
print(all_tags)

all_li_tags = [tags.findall('li') for tags in all_tags]
print(all_li_tags)
```

and a lot of other variations :(

Tried to create those 3 different lists including the address, price, and link to the property

Comment: Try grabbing `#grid-search-results` then grab all `li` or directly `.property-card-data`.

Comment: How are you fetching the html?  requests?  selenium?

Comment: @Daviid Can you write it to me ?
data = soup.select(selector='#grid-search-results')['li]?

Comment: @JohnGordon yes my soup is from the requests.get and then getting the response.text to a soup

Comment: `requests` cannot process javascript.  I think that is the problem.  Most modern websites depend on javascript.

Comment: @JohnGordon I’m following a course on Udemy and it’s from 3 years ago and she used requests as well. There’s any chance that things has changed and now I can use this website with javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

Tagged with `selenium` I assume that you will get the completely rendered source text, with which you can select your elements as follows (select your elements by constant id or tag and try to avoid dynamic identifiers such as class names):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager(version='114.0.5735.90').install())

driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

data = []

for e in soup.select('#grid-search-results article'):
    data.append({
        'address': e.address.text,
        'condition': e.span.text,
        'link': e.a.get('href') if e.a.get('href').startswith('https') else 'https://www.zillow.com'+e.a.get('href')
    })

data
```

*Keep in mind, that this will only pick the information from first page, you need to iterate all following result pages, if you like to scrape more then the first 41 itmes.*

Furthermore, instead of different lists, you should choose a more structured form of storage like a `dict`, what could be easily transformed into `dataframe`, ...:

```
[{'address': '1190 Mission at Trinity Place | 1190 Mission St, San Francisco, CA',
  'price': '$2,199+ 1 bd',
  'link': 'https://www.zillow.com/apartments/san-francisco-ca/1190-mission-at-trinity-place/5XjVtb/'},
 {'address': '1188 Mission at Trinity Place | 1188 Mission St, San Francisco, CA',
  'price': '$2,099+ 1 bd',
  'link': 'https://www.zillow.com/apartments/san-francisco-ca/1188-mission-at-trinity-place/5XjN4q/'},
 {'address': 'Soma at 788 | 788 Harrison St, San Francisco, CA',
  'price': '$2,767+ 1 bd',
  'link': 'https://www.zillow.com/apartments/san-francisco-ca/soma-at-788/5XkGzw/'},...]
```

---

An alternative would be to access the JSON requests of the api, may check: [JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) or giving incorrect data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76209111/14460824)

Comment: I’ll try it when I’m back home thank you :)

Comment: I'm getting only 9 apartments instead of 62 or so

Comment: You tagged your question with `selenium` so you should get up to 41 items, if you use `requests` you will not get the rendered version of source as @John Gorndon commented. If `requests` is needed check the link I posted as alternative.